# Extract NuGet packager in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to extract Nuget Package in Azure DevOps as part of build. I don't have dedicated plugin in Azure DevOps to unpack Nuget package. I just use zip extractor.

I see some errors,

> stderr:  2019-10-25T14:28:54.9806038Z ERROR: Can't allocate required
>   memory!

I have attached pic as well[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many nuget packages are in your project? As my test, I upload two nuget packages in my project.

[image]

If I set the Archive file patterns as `*.nupkg`

[image]

I will get the same error message as yours.

[image]

But if I add two Extract files tasks and set the Archive file patterns as below.
[image]

The task will run successed.
[image]
[image]

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Add the [NuGet Restore Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops) before your build step.